# How to serialize a type that might be an arbitrary string?

Tags: rust, serde

I have an enum type that is defined as either one of list of predefined strings or an arbitrary value (i.e. code that uses this type potentially wants to handle a few specific cases a certain way and also allow an arbitrary string).

I'm trying to represent this in Rust with serde the following way:

```rs
#[derive(Serialize, Debug)]
pub enum InvalidatedAreas {
  #[serde(rename = "all")]
  All,
  #[serde(rename = "stacks")]
  Stacks,
  #[serde(rename = "threads")]
  Threads,
  #[serde(rename = "variables")]
  Variables,
  String(String),
}
```

When used as a member, I would like to serialize the above enum as simply a string value:

```rs
#[derive(Serialize, Debug)]
struct FooBar {
  foo: InvalidatedAreas,
  bar: InvalidatedAreas,
}

fn main() {
  let foob = FooBar { 
    foo: types::InvalidatedAreas::Stacks, 
    bar: types::InvalidatedAreas::String("hello".to_string()) 
  };
  let j = serde_json::to_string(&foob)?;
  println!("{}", j);
}
```

What I get is:

```
{"foo":"stacks","bar":{"String":"hello"}}
```

But I need

```
{"foo":"stacks","bar":"hello"}
```

If I add `#[serde(untagged)]` to the enum definition, I get

```rs
{"foo":null,"bar":"hello"}
```

How can I serialize this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've arrived at the following solution. It requires a bit of repetition, but it's not so bad. I'll leave the question open in case someone has a better idea.

```rs
impl ToString for InvalidatedAreas {
  fn to_string(&self) -> String {
    match &self {
      InvalidatedAreas::All => "all",
      InvalidatedAreas::Stacks => "stacks",
      InvalidatedAreas::Threads => "threads",
      InvalidatedAreas::Variables => "variables",
      InvalidatedAreas::String(other) => other
    }
    .to_string()
  }
}

impl Serialize for InvalidatedAreas {
  fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
      S: serde::Serializer,
    {
      serializer.serialize_str(&self.to_string())
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You could change your impl of `ToString` to an impl of `From` or `Into` and then use Serde's `into` attribute. Then you don't need to implement `Serialize`.

Comment: I can't find an `into` attribute in the current documentation, but it seems to work regardless if I provide an Into implementation. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: `into` is documented in https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html